# call Powershell in VBS with parameters

Tags: powershell, vbscript, arguments

I need one, simple thing. I am using VBS to call Powershell and I like to execute it with parameter (variable from VBS)

> Dim Input
>
> Input = InputBox("Enter User's alias to check")
> Set objShell = CreateObject("Wscript.Shell")
>
> objShell.run("powershell.exe -noexit -file .\ps_v2.ps1") &Input

As you see it is pretty short and easy code, PS_v2.ps1 works fine when executed in PS console directly with argument. I need variable Input to be used as parameter.

In PS console i just type

> .\ps_V2.ps1 Input

and it works. So it must be somewhere in ObjShell.run. When I used echo just to check if the variable is assigned correctly i got a correct output.

Result is that PowerShell window appear just for a second and disappear. I think it is not taking "Input" in consideration at all.

So make long story short. How should look the VBS line to call PS script with argument? Just like ".\ps_V2.ps1 Input" in PS console.

Thanks a lot in advance!

Edited: 19.2.2014 - 16:32
**Thank You Ekkehard.Horner, works fine**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The concatenation (&) is at the wrong palce:

```
Set objShell = CreateObject("Wscript.Shell") objShell.run("powershell.exe -noexit -file .\ps_v2.ps1") &Input

Set objShell = CreateObject("Wscript.Shell") objShell.run("powershell.exe -noexit -file .\ps_v2.ps1 " & Input)
```

Comment: Confirmed, works fine. In my case the PS command required a forward slash `./ps_v2.ps1` and the script required the `param($Input)`.
This allows to take advantage and use/apply backwordlooking Regex patterns not available in VBscript and still run 'old' VBscripts matured over the years.